# FFMPEG Split RGBA image sequence to rgb.mp4 and alpha.mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rgb, alpha

I want to split input to two outputs: `rgb.mp4` and `alpha.mp4` in one command. Attempted command:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 25 -start_number 0 -i "D:\wfh\seq\Rays_%%5d.png" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -level 5.1  "rgb.mp4" "alpha.mp4"
```

Using alpha extract will only produce gray scale output (if am not wrong), but I want both RGB and grayscale output in one go.

Comment: i mean, if we put -vf alpha extract we get grayscale output only... (if am not wrong). I mean to say, i want both RGB and gray scale outputs at one go or in one command.When i run the command, it shud produce both RGB.mp4 and grayscale.mp4. Is this clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [alphaextract](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#alphaextract) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input_%5d.png -filter_complex "[0]alphaextract[alpha]" -map 0 -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 rgb.mp4 -map "[alpha]" -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 alpha.mp4
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!
Are -pix_fmt yuv420p and format=yuv420p both mean same.

Comment: There were two issues. 

Input and output rgb color mismatch.
----------------------------------------------------------------
input is pure red (r=255,g=0,b=0).
output is (r=255,g=24,b=0) (green is not zero)
How to fix this?

RGB and alpha position mismatch after conversion.(fixed)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
For that we have to use format=420p for alpha as well
-filter_complex "[0]format=yuv420p[rgb];[0]alphaextract,format=yuv420p[a]".

Comment: I just imported input(png sequence) and output(converted mp4 files) in after effects and checked with eye dropper. input color values are (r=255,g=0,b=0) and converted mp4 color values are (r=255,g=24,b=0).

Link to example
------------------------------
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kFUAe7VzZmtUpcB4LuBfwMwb8NJmovqh?usp=sharing

Comment: Also using libx264rgb producing this result
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12D48j8NA-uNDKvMMADhS19_Vw0IJtGFd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If i remove format=yuv420p and use libx264rgb it gives error initializing complex filters.
 -filter_complex "[0][rgb];[0]alphaextract[a]", Is this correct.?How to assign input to rgb.[0]copy[rgb]??

Comment: Ok, lets start again.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n3QeLOUh0T06P0_YLYxnemUHetw0wNJb/view?usp=sharing

The link above has sample png image sequence (RGBA) of 25 frames(small size).

Task is to Convert that image sequence to two mp4 files namely rgb.mp4 and alpha.mp4 without color shift(input rgb = output rgb) and without position change.

Please download that and test for me.

I tried "setparams=colorspace=bt709" which solves color shift but still green channel is 1 not 0.

Comment: @manjunathkaranth This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need MP4? Why not just use the PNG sequence itself, or mux the PNG sequence into a supported container?

Comment: i need 2 mp4 h264 files, rgb and alpha as it is low in file size and later use alpha output as track matte in after effects. and prerendering a video with alpha. splitting into rgb and alpha in h264 mp4 and comp it again as matte.this reduces file size and final render time .I know there will be a generation loss in quality. But thats fine as of now.

Comment: Hi llogan, am running out of time, i know what am doing. i could have done RGB and alpha conversions to mp4 seperately. But i just want to save time by half by processing once and output 2 files.. thats it.. I shared drive link as well on which am testing. Please see if u can help at the earliest.

Comment: @manjunathkaranth Did you see I updated the command on 24 July?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, above code is working, but in after effects the imported mp4 is completely green.It seems that the issue is with libx264rgb.

Comment: @manjunathkaranth I doubt Adobe After Effects supports H.264 with RGB colorspace. I considered this and is one reason I asked if it was an XY problem.

Comment: ok, all working ok! i just need one more help.Am dropping "-pix_fmt yuv420p" coz all my RGBA input sources have random width and height.Below is final code am using:
-----------
ffmpeg -i  input_%5d.png  -filter_complex "[0]alphaextract[a]" -map 0 -c:v libx264 -crf 5 -vf setparams='colorspace=bt709' rgb.mp4 -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -crf 5  alpha.mp4
----------
There is problem in above code.. it converts fine, rgb.mp4 is fine, but alpha.mp4 is fully green and doesn't play.Need inputs here, please...

Comment: @manjunathkaranth You really shouldn't be using H.264 for this, but you seem insistent. Consider QTRLE, utvideo, or PNG. Anyway, you'll need to use `alphaextract,format=yuv420p` if you want H.264.

Comment: Sure man, i had enough information from you to fix. Thank you so much